# Can't select People (@) when adding a comment in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

Since last Friday, I have a weird issue with VSTS. I no longer have the option to mention people in comments when reviewing a Pull request. However, the option still works properly in the Team Room chat.

In the window of adding a comment, I only see `save (enter) - cancel (esc) - workitems (#)`, while for other colleagues it is `save (enter) - cancel (esc) - workitems (#) - people (@)`

My question: What did I do to turn it off and how can I enable it again?

**update**
I deleted cookies and emptied browser cache, I tried using different browsers (also in private / incognito mode), but it didn't help.
I also tried to log in on a different machine, while a colleague logged in on mine. Still no success.

**update #2**
I also tried to remove / re-add my account to VSTS. First it looked good, I got back the option to mention others, but after a day it's gone again.

**update #3**
I found a workaround, if I type in`@<email-address>` in the comment, it is displayed properly, the person gets a notification, etc. But still, the dropdown is not shown.

Comment: Try to clear browser cache and then check if it works.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I tried it, see my update with the details.

Comment: Voting to close as per original author's comment: I got it now. First I had to remove my user account from VSTS, then I was added again. After login, I got back the People (@) option for pull requests.